# How to register AuthenticationSuccessHandler or SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler in Spring Security's SAML extension?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml

tldr; What's the appropriate way to register either a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler or configure the SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler to set the redirect URL Spring Security's SAML extension after a successful authentication?

I am new to Spring and Spring Security, but I've had some success getting the SAML extension to work for a Single Sign-On application. However, I've run into a problem where Okta (the IDP) and my application will loop continuously after successful authentication instead of going to the original URL. My suspicion is that this is caused by the fact that I am using Vaadin as well as Spring and once the Vaadin servlet loads it is doing something funky with or ignoring the Spring filters entirely. This is suggested a possible problem and solution in a blog article on [combining filter-based Spring Security with Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/filter-based-spring-security-in-vaadin-applications) where the proposed solution is to register an AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

However, this is not as simple with the Spring Security SAML Extension as it is with, say, a simple form login or OpenID. For example, with a form login registing a success handler is as easy as

```
http.formLogin().successHandler(handler);
```

No such option is available with the SAML Extension. However, in another post Vladimír Schäfer (see "Spring saml - how remember request parameter when initiate login on SP, and procesing them after IdP response) suggests changing the AuthenticationSuccessHandler to a SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler. The documentation suggests that this would be the perfect way to do it. However, I would prefer not to subclass SAMLEntryPoint.

My current SecurityConfiguration is entirely Java-based and follows Matt Raible's article on using Spring and Okta together. The SecurityConfiguration is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable() // Disable Spring's CSRF protection and use Vaadin's.
        .authorizeRequests() // Everything else: Do SAML SSO
            // Allow everyone to attempt to login
            .antMatchers("/root/saml*").permitAll()
            // But make sure all other requests are authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // Create a completely new session
            .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession()
            .and()
            // Configure the saml properties
        .apply(saml())
            .serviceProvider()
                .keyStore()
                    .storeFilePath("saml/keystore.jks")
                    .password(this.password)
                    .keyname(this.keyAlias)
                    .keyPassword(this.password)
                    .and()
                .protocol("https")
                // Do I need to adjust this localhost piece?
                .hostname(String.format("%s:%s", "localhost", this.port))
                .basePath("/")
                .and()      
                // Load the metadata from the stored properties
            .identityProvider().metadataFilePath(this.metadataUrl);
}
```

```

What's the best way to register the AuthenticationSuccessHandler or configure the SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler? Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to registering a custom handler is to configure the Spring SAML extension using the sample securityContext.xml file provided in the Sample program. Full details are available by carefully reading the [Spring SAML Extension guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0-RC2-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/chapter-configuration.html). If you are using Spring Boot, you need to tell it to import the securityContext.xml file by adding an @ImportResource annotation. In my case, I removed all the code from my security configuration class, but left the annotations and added the @ImportResource as follows:

```
/**
 * This class is the main security configuration for working with the
 * Single-Sign On SAML backend. All it does it import the security context file
 * and configure other annotation-based options. All of the real configuration
 * options are in WEB-INF/securityContext.xml.
 * 
 * @author Jay Jay Billings
 *
 */
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @Configuration
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
 @ImportResource("WEB-INF/securityContext.xml")
 public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}
```

Once the securityContext.xml file is in place and reconfigure for your application, you can add a custom handler in the successRedirectHandler bean:

```
<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"
    class="com.example.app.customSuccessHandler">
</bean>
```

That is the answer to my question, but it did not fix my redirect loop problem on its own. The solution to the redirect loop also required 1) fixing the entity base URL in the MetadataGenerator bean, and 2) fixing the security:intercept-url pattern value to account for my modified (non-root) base URL. For information on the latter, see "This webpage has a redirect loop in spring-security application" on this site.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using:

```
@Bean
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
        new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
                super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            }           
        };
    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
    return successRedirectHandler;
}
```

It seems to avoid needing a separate securityContext.xml file.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers. I accepted my own because it includes more details on how to do it and upon further reflection I think there are serious merits to using the XML file over the Java code. Basically, I think the Java API on HTTPSecurity is a little wanting.

Comment: Sorry, but where do you set successRedirectHandler() in your extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class? thanks